# Connecting to a SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio and trying to connect to the Northwind database. I use the following connection command...

```
Data Source=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\\v3.5\\Samples\\Northwind.sdf;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

I have also tried

```
Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI
```

both cases I get an error -

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

I can connect to an online database but not on a remote one. I have checked the config manager and all services are running.

Any helps please

Comment: What Database are you trying to connect to, your first connection string is for SQL Server CE (Compact Edition). Have you tried Connectionstrings.com  http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Have you checked the database is actually running, and that it is allowing connections for the user / credentials you are sending?

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of collections of connection strings so you can get help from here...

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Comment: Use proper SQL Server Instance name and if you are using MDF file path then please put this file into App_Data folder because Program Files folder is restricted folder and IIS works fine in virtual directory...

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio has tools to connect to databases. Using Server Explorer, you can choose which SQL Server you want to connect to and then choose the database from a list. Once you have successfully connected to one, its properties mention the connection string to use. No need to guess.